# Apache 2.4 cannot proceed due to conflicts with Module mpm_prefork

Tags: 14.04, apache2, apache2.4

I have just updated from 12.04 to 14.04 and now have difficulty setting up Apache 2.4  I am getting the following error:

```
Setting up apache2 (2.4.10-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
ERROR: Module mpm_prefork is enabled - cannot proceed due to conflicts. It needs to be disabled first!
dpkg: error processing package apache2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apache2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I disable the mpm_prefork so that Apache can continue?

Answer (score 8):

I would use the proper command to disable a mod in Apache:

```
sudo a2dismod mpm_prefork
```

Comment: I just get `Module mpm_prefork already disabled`. My situation is that php7.2 didn't install itself into apache2.4 correctly, and I can't fix it because this command doesn't work.

Comment: Thank, For me other disables was needed before: `sudo a2dismod php8.1; sudo a2dismod mpm_prefork; sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Answer (score 5):

You should try to remove the symlinks `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.{conf,load}`:

```
rm /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.{conf,load}
```

Then relaunch the configuration of the `apache2` package:

```
apt-get install -f
```

Or:

```
apt-get install apache2
```

But more important, you should ask yourself how these were installed there before hand. You might have copied an older `/etc/apache2` directory with these (for instance) before launching `apt-get install apache2`.

Answer (score 3):

[There are apparently 3 different versions of this module](https://askubuntu.com/a/1000700/573611) (`mpm_worker` vs `mpm_prefork` vs `mpm_event`), and the error code can be misleading. Try disabling all three variants and then reinstalling. In my case (Mint 19.1/Ubuntu 18.04, php7.2), was the third:

```
root@machine:/var/www/html# sudo a2dismod mpm_worker
Module mpm_worker already disabled
root@machine:/var/www/html# sudo a2dismod mpm_prework
ERROR: Module mpm_prework does not exist!
root@machine:/var/www/html# sudo a2dismod mpm_event
Module mpm_event disabled.
```

After this, installing the apache php mod worked (`sudo a2enmod php7.2`) and the code was executed correctly.