# apache2 php not executed

Tags: apache2, php

When I go to pages in localhost, only php code is shown. This version:

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.0.10-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.10-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

I tried to do [Upgrade to 16.04. php7 not working in browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760907/upgrade-to-16-04-php7-not-working-in-browser) but

```
sudo a2enmod php7.0
ERROR: Module php7.0 does not exist!
```

When I click tab while

```
sudo a2enmod php7
```

it completes to

```
sudo a2enmod php7.0.load.dpkg-dist
```

but result is same

```
$ sudo a2enmod php7.0.load.dpkg-dist 
ERROR: Module php7.0.load.dpkg-dist does not exist!
```

I installed php like this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove php5-common -y
sudo apt-get purge php5-common -y
sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-fpm php7.0-mysql -y
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove -y
```

I did not enable fpm.

I have all [these packages](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/php.html).

```
$ a2enmod php
php5.6                 php7.0.load.dpkg-dist
$ a2enmod php5.6
Considering dependency mpm_prefork for php5.6:
Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_prefork:
ERROR: Module mpm_event is enabled - cannot proceed due to conflicts. It needs to be disabled first!
Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork:
ERROR: Could not enable dependency mpm_prefork for php5.6, aborting
```

I delete 5.6 but it's still shown; why?

Comment: How did you install php7 ?

Comment: I had 2 php, 5.6 an 7. i deleted all php and installed  sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-fpm php7.0-mysql -y and sudo apt-get -y update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0 php7.0-common php7.0-gd php7.0-mysql php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-curl php7.0-intl php7.0-xsl php7.0-mbstring php7.0-zip php7.0-bcmath php7.0-iconv

Comment: Would you please [**edit**](http://askubuntu.com/posts/822058/edit) your question and update your codes which is more convenient for us to see. Also, in the meantime, would you update the output for `locate bin/php`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to choose between [mpm_worker](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/worker.html) vs [mpm_prefork](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/prefork.html) (or [mpm_event](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/event.html)). Only one Apache [MPM module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mpm.html). Try:

```
sudo a2dismod mpm_worker
sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Take a look at [this excellent answer](https://serverfault.com/a/383634/407820) at Serverfault.